# When to rotate a client TLS certificate?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority

What is the recommended rotation period of a TLS/client certificate? I have seen organizations rotating at half life and some that rotate only 30-50 days before expiry.

For example, for a certificate valid for 1 year, do I rotate at 6 months or at 11 months? Is there any recommendation to rotate at 80% of the life of a certificate?

Comment: Can you clarify the question. Are you specifically talking about client certs, or server certs and client certs? Clients for what, VPN, web sites, other? How are the private keys stored, on PIV cards, people's mobile phones?

Comment: I'm talking about client certificates (If you have a recommendation for server certs, I would be happy to hear it). New certificates will be bound to new private keys although I'm not sure how the key pair is relevant to the question

Comment: Essentially you're looking for a pointer to a Best Practices or Guidance document for key rotation, right? Take some extreme examples: VPN certs issued to employees' BYOD devices in a small company, vs the certs on government-issued PIV cards in the US DoD network, vs client certs protecting credit card data in a PCI-DSS environment. Basically, there's no single right answer to your question; it depends on the security requirements of your organization, and whether you are subject to any industry regulations. If you can add more context, that would help direct you to the right docs.

Comment: Ah, I see you've accepted an answer, so I guess that request for clarification is moot :P Good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The amount of time before expiration that someone decides to renew the certificate has to do with *continuity* rather than *security*.  In short, **you should leave yourself enough time to rotate, based on "normal" turnaround time and then adding some more time for padding.**  The people rotating at half-life are leaving a LOT of padding.

The certificate is presumed valid and secure until it expires, or it is revoked.  Initiating the renewal doesn't imply that the certificate is  less valid in any way.

But consider a certificate that expires in 3 days - and takes a week to renew.  There will be a shortfall where the old certificate has expired, and the new one is not yet in place.

These sort of time crunches are commonly multiplied by inefficiencies on both ends of the chain, and in many cases there is *institutional trauma* from *that one time somebody forgot and everything blew up*.  Their solution?  Leave a bigger buffer, and renew the certificate farther out, with more time before the expiration "wall".

Comment: This was my train of thought as well. I will wait for a while to see if someone else replies else will mark this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer above is marked as correct, I think the spirit of the question is "what rotation period provides adequate security". The lack of real answers to security questions on the internet continues unabated.. Although I appreciate the answer above related to avoiding expiration because it prevents the security inconveniences that drive the tendancy to work around security policies.

**Background**: Certificate rotation on a server is performed on a roughly 90 day to 2 year rhythm.  Some justification for this periodicity:

-All secrets must be rotated. Any secret, no matter how secure we believe it to be stored, at some point may become compromised.
-Certificate Authorities, often the target of angst from both consumers and providers of security and secure infrastructure, have no idea how well you are managing the certificates they grant. Therefore they must take an aggressive position to ensure rotation does an adequate job of maintaining security in those situations where the private keys aren't adequately protected. And I'm guessing that's the majority case.

Servers are considered to be secured from trespassers in most situations. That implies a dedicated, locked room. In some cases private keys are stored in an HSM or some hardened security container that prevents easy theft. Yet... they are rotated (roughly) every 90 days to 2 years (max). Of course rotation provides a revenue stream but we can agree keys should be rotated.

**Answer:**
Now- the great question above in the comments about "What kind of client certificate" is important.

Smart cards have a client certificate built in. They are tamper proofed, and the private key will never be visible outside of the card. Smart cards that get stolen (or the corresponding CA is compromised) are generally handled by revocation.  Smart cards can last between 3 and 10 years.

If you are using a mutual authentication certificate for www or ssh from a PC , the safety of the private keys are MUCH more in question. In these cases, a 90 day rotation period that roughly matches password change periods seems warranted. Certainly if your device doesn't fall in the "well protected" category mentioned above, I think it would be prudent to do 90 day rotation.

Comment: The answer is marked as correct because the original asker of the question felt it answered the question. I have downvoted your post because you have answered what you think the question should be, not what the OP asked.

Comment: LOL thanks for acting on his behalf; the community sure appreciates it. In the mean time, the reason there was so much discussion above about additional information is that... The original question was not answered.

Comment: Greg - the answer was accepted in Aug 2018. Which means the OP felt it did meet their requirements. Your assumption that the question asked was in some way different goes against the OP. Please focus on the points in our [about] and [answer] pages. Thank you.

Comment: the rules probably encourage you to vote down misleading information. Is this misleading? 
Googling for myself I found the usual miss on security. I answered "What is the recommended rotation period". existing expiration is mentioned; you are correct. The answera bit obvious: "Before it expires". If you think it will take you longer, leave extra time? I don't understand how someone wouldn't answer that for themselves. Anyway, I hope someone wanders here and sees my "wrong answer" and builds better security into their certificates as a result.